# How to transformed a dataframe according to a defined schema

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want a dataframe to have exactly these columns:

```
columns=['index', 'count_1','count_2', 'count_3', 'count_4', 'count_5']
```

So if a given dataframe dosen´t have, for example, 'count_2', I want to add `count_2` to the dataframe with all values = 0

If this dataframe has another columns that is not on `columns` list I want to drop the whole column.

example:

Input dataframe:

```
'index' 'count_1','count_2' 'count_3' 'count_4' 'count_5'
  1        10        12        45        0        23
```

is OK!

The dataframe:

```
'index' 'count_1', 'count_3' 'count_4' 'count_5'
  1        10         45        0        23
```

should be transformed to:

```
'index' 'count_1','count_2' 'count_3' 'count_4' 'count_5'
  1        10        0        45        0        23
```

the dataframe

```
'index' 'count_1','count_2' 'count_3' 'count_4' 'count_5'   'count_6'
   1        10        0        45        0        23          11
```

should be transformed to:

```
index' 'count_1','count_2' 'count_3' 'count_4' 'count_5'
  1        10        0        45        0        23
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) per columns with replace missing values to `0`:

```
columns=['index', 'count_1','count_2', 'count_3', 'count_4', 'count_5']

df = df.reindex(columns=columns, fill_value=0)
```